# What does 「まさかそれが、」 mean at the beginning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> **まさかそれが**、あのような惨劇{さんげき}を引{ひ}き起{お}こす事{こと}になるとは、知{し}るよしもなかったのです。

What if 「まさかそれが、」 is at the beginning of a sentence? What does it mean? Would it mean something like "That's it,"?

Comment: It would help if you provide the rest of the sentence and some context.

Comment: Does it help comprehension if you split the two? `まさか` and `それが`. There really isn't a special meaning, just those two expressions in one chunk. `まさか` is often used to show how surprised someone is that something happened.

Answer (score 2):

まさか is a *guiding adverb* that leads to an expression of something unexpected. それが is the subject for the verb 引き起こす.

Answer (score 0):

まさかそれが...

I think it literally means "Don't tell me that is..."